# Rain hitting down pipes

Tags: noise, rain

New downpipe installed outside bedroom window so when it rains there is a constant loud pinging noise as rain hits it, any ideas to stop this?

Comment: are you sure that the noise is caused by the raindrops hitting pipe? ...... could it be the sound of water running down inside the pipe?

Comment: Just to confirm, can you post a pic of the install?

Answer (score 1):

Hang a plastic chain in the pipe, all the way from top to bottom. The water will trickle down the chain instead of hitting the walls.

Comment: ... does this cause any problems in freezing climes?

Comment: No it does not cause problems in freezing climates.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear without more details what exactly the problem is. However, most likely you are hearing droplets of water dripping from the gutter at the top of the pipe, falling all the way to the bottom, where they hit and make noise.

If so, then you should be able to remedy the problem by adjusting the angle of the drainpipe slightly, so that the droplet drips onto the side of the pipe higher up, avoiding the sound. You'll have to look at the current angle of the pipe, figure out which side the drip must be coming from, and then orient the pipe accordingly.

Adjusting the pipe side-to-side may involve simply changing where the hold-down straps are. If the pipe requires adjustment front-to-back, you might need some kind of spacer at the bottom, depending on which direction the pipe needs to go.